# Iphone Leaks NSString

Tags: iphone, memory-leaks, nsstring

I have leaks in the following code :

```
NSString * string;
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)str{
   string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", str];
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {

   NSString * value = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];

}
```

But I don't understand what's the prob. Can you help me please? :s

Comment: There's no leak. Just you're creating a lot of temporary objects.

Comment: Is there a reason why you think there is a leak? From what I can tell all of the string instances in this case are autoreleased.

Comment: Have you got an NSAutoreleasePool setup, to deal witht the autoreleased NSStrings?

Comment: Yes I have an autorelease pool. I see the leak in the leak instrument.

Answer (score 0):

Is the variable "string" always allocated from the autorelease pool?  If not, then the first function could be suspect as "string", if it is already initialized with another string, is not released prior to the assignment.  That would leak.